# checkbox not showing due to name attribute

Tags: jquery, html

If I have a checkbox which has this name attribute below:

`name="answerName[True]"`

How come when I peform this jquery line below that it does not show the checkbox?

`$(this).closest('.option').siblings('.answer').find('input[name=answerName[Yes]]').show();`

if the name attribute was this:

`name="answerNameTrue"`

and the jquery was this:

`$(this).closest('.option').siblings('.answer').find('input[name=answerNameYes]').show();`

then it does show but how come when I put [] brackets around it that it suddenly doesn't work and not show the check box?

Comment: Your [yes] are simply conflicting with the selectors' bracket

Comment: answerNameTrue and answerNameYes can't be equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use quotation marks:

```
$(this).closest('.option').siblings('.answer').find('input[name="answerName[Yes]"]').show();
```

Comment: Yeah putting quotations in will help solve this problem. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

`True`  is a javascript Keyword.

That might be one of the reasons this gets messed up..

Try to put the attribute in Quotes and then try..

```
.find('input[name="answerName[Yes]"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [yes] are simply conflicting with the selectors' bracket

Jquery will parse :

```
find('input[name=answerName[Yes]]')
```

and will keep :

```
find('input[name=answerName[Yes]');
```

So at the end you have a [ that jquery don't know what to do with it + an extra ] at the end of your selector.

Try escaping it :

```
find('input[name=answerName\[Yes\]]')
```

or

```
find('input[name="answerName[Yes]"]')
```